# Need help on Python queue

Tags: python-3.x, queue

So I was trying to answer a question regarding Queues. But I have no idea how to do this. Could someone help me answer this question

"Write a function that creates a queue, enqueues the letters in the given parameter string to the queue and dequeues them off as indicated by the ‘*’s in the parameter string. A letter in the expression indicates an enqueue to the queue, and an asterisk indicates a dequeue operation."

The test is:

```
print(work_on_queue('EAS*Y*QUE***ST***IO*N***'))
```

and the result should be:

```
EASYQUESTION
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def work_on_queue(s):
   r=[]
   for c in s:
     if c != '*':
       r.append(c)
   return ''.join(r)
```

Comment: it says i need to use a queue to solve this question